# Getting glmnet to select excatly given number of features?

Tags: r, feature-selection, lasso, glmnet

I am using glmnet for feature selection, given a gaussian dependent variable. Part of my code is like this:

```
lambda_seq <- 10^seq(2, -2, by = -0.1)
cv_output <- cv.glmnet(data.matrix(x_vars), y_var, alpha = 1, lambda = lambda_seq, nfolds = 5)
```

How can I use glmnet to select exactly three (continuous) predictor variables (features), from a large set? Three is best for me, given my limited dataset size. Moreover, the chosen predictors should not be correlated much (say, maximum correlation is less than 0.7 for each pair).

I guess I can write a loop and change lambda till I get three predictors. But is there something more efficient and elegant? If not, what is the best strategy for getting the optimal lambda (one that gives exactly three predictors) with a loop?

To give some more context, I want to formulate a 3-variable model as part of a leave-one-out cross validation loop. Hence, the steps should be automated.

Comment: a) IIRC the authors recommend that you specify only the numbe of lambdas to try - they select the values b) cv_output will have all the lambdas eg if you plot you should see CV error with the associated number of parameters. so you should be able to simply extract that same information as a table too

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. But please the last para I have added: I need an automated solution, so that it goes into a LOOCV loop.

Comment: of course, you could automate @seanv507 approach by simply checking which lambdas provide the desired number of nonzeros and, say, choosing the middlemost one.

Comment: How many total predictors do you have? I think that choosing only 3 is maybe not the best idea, but if all subsets (with 3 predictors) is computationally feasible I think that would be better.

Comment: @wzbillings I have around 4000 predictors, many of which are correlated with each other. However, my sample size is only 34, hence I prefer a parsimonious model.

Comment: The 10 observations per predictor rule is just a rule of thumb. If you want a parsimonious model, I would recommend using CV, but instead of choosing the penalty with the least CV error, chose the largest lambda with an error that is within one SE of the CV error. If your model has 3 or 10 or 1000 predictors or whatever after selecting lambda like that, IMO that is valuable information.

Comment: But if you really want exactly 3 predictors, I think the internals of `plot.glmnet()` might be helpful. You can copy the part that gets the number of predictors and the penalty into a format that can be plotted, and then use that to select the first penalty value with 3 predictors.

Comment: All-subset regression doesn't work well.  And no method is likely to find the "right" predictors.  See [this](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/multivar#sec-multivar-variable-selection).

Comment: @FrankHarrell I don't really understand something: On the link you provided, you state that reducing the collinearity in the original feature set is necessary to avoid implementing noise variables in the Prediction Features Set, however i have seen in your many posts that for a predictive goal, one should take the whole feature set. Is there a detail i am missing or something i haven't understood ?

Or is the information provided by the link specific to stepwise, and not to any other feature selection method ?

Comment: That's not exactly what I meant.  I mean that feature selection almost never works as intended, and the disaster turns into an outright catastrophe when there is collinearity.  For prediction as well as for interpretation it is often better to reduce dimensionality (data reduction, AKA unsupervised learning) so you have fewer parameters to estimate using the response variable.  Methods include variable clustering and sparse principal component analysis.  See [this](https://hbiostat.org/bbr/hdata) and Chapters 8 and 24 of [this](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code returns model performance for a cv.glmnet process, only if there is a model with the desired number of variables. It may not exist if you are in ridge. So only if elsatic net or lasso.

```
    #Calculation of model performance for a model with a given number of parameters


alf       <-  YOUR_ALPHA
X         <-  YOUR_EXPLANATORY_VARIABLES
Y         <-  YOUR_RESPONSE_VARIABLE
nbVarFixe <-  YOUR_FIXED_NUMBER_OF_DESIRED_VARIABLES_IN_FINAL_MODEL


lasso.cv  <- cv.glmnet(X,Y,alpha=alf,type.measure = "mse",nfolds=10)    



     if (length(which(lasso.cv$nzero == nbVarFixe)) == 0) {  
                                      
     #If no model meets the requirements, nothing to return
                                    
          R2_lasso_nbVarFixe             <- NA
          n_var_lasso_nbVarFixe          <- NA
          liste_variable_lasso_nbVarFixe <- NA       
         
     }else{                     #If a model with desired number of variables exists

          lambda.select         <- min(lasso.cv$lambda[which(lasso.cv$nzero == nbVarFixe)])                 # choice of model with X variables
          liste_coef_lasso      <- coef(lasso.cv, s = lambda.select)                                        
      
          # liste des coef
          liste_variable_lasso_nbVarFixe  <- liste_coef_lasso@Dimnames[[1]][which(liste_coef_lasso != 0 ) ] # list of selected variables
          n_var_lasso_nbVarFixe           <- length(liste_variable_lasso_nbVarFixe)                         #Number of selected variables in the model (just in case)
          liste_variable_lasso_nbVarFixe  <- if (n_var_lasso_nbVarFixe>5) {" > 5 "}                         #irrelevant here, but it came from my script where it is useful
                                             else                         {liste_variable_lasso_nbVarFixe}

          liste_variable_lasso_nbVarFixe  <- paste( liste_variable_lasso_nbVarFixe , collapse = " ")        #printout des variables séléctionnées
          MSE_lasso             <- lasso.cv$cvm[which(lasso.cv$lambda==lambda.select)]                      # calcul de l'erreur MSE
          EQM_lasso             <- sqrt(MSE_lasso)                                                          # erreur en valeur terrain
          R2_lasso_nbVarFixe    <- 1-(MSE_lasso/var(Y))                                                     # variance expliquee
                                  }
```

The solution here is that "lasso.cv$nzero" contains the number of non-zeros regression coefficients, it means that it contains for each produced models the number of variables selected by EN or LASSO.

This is a code i copy pasted from one of my projects and it seems to me there is a confusion in terminology between many packages when it comes to the parameters of EN or LASSO. Here, "alpha" is also referred to as "gamma" in other packages.

Comment: Thanks! This works well. I did not know that there was the option of doing: "lambda.select<- min(lasso.cv$lambda[which(lasso.cv$nzero == nbVarFixe)])".

Comment: Yup, the solution here is that "lasso.cv$nzero" contains the number of non-zeros regression coefficients, it means that it contains for each produced models the number of variables selected by EN or LASSO.

Comment: I have edited the question, adding in the new requirement about correlation of the predictors.

Comment: To be more specific: the above method gives me correlated variables (correlation > 0.7) as part of the set of predictor variables selected. Any way to avoid/overcome this?

Comment: i would say it is part of the lasso method, but it should not be really a problem as the effect is split between all these explanatory variables, thanks to the shinking (if i have correctly understood the lasso). 
If you want to avoid this, you may want to apply a filter before running lasso.
Many solutions exist, i don't know them.
For exemple: Creating a subset of features correlated to your response variable, but which are correlated to each other below a certain threshold (which you chose). That solution is not mine, i was given it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am a bit surprised that lasso selects such correlated variables, but I cannot find any "bug" in my code. Your suggestion to filter the input (predictor) dataset to create a non-correlated set is interesting. Do you know of any method to do this? Especially ones that take into account the response variable?

Comment: the one i was given does so: Select the feature most correlated to the response variable, add it in the future useful feature set. From the leftover pool of features, select the next one which is the most correlated to the response variable but which is correlated to the features inside the useful feature set below a certain threshold

Comment: (80%, 70%, 60% up to you). Considering your dataset, you might want to be very strict with the collinearity in order to greatly reduce the variability in the features selected by Lasso.
That method is really stable, changing one or two individuals in the training set is not going to change a lot to the selected feature set (however your set is really low in amount of individuals so i don't know)

Comment: Whatever you do either bootstrap the whole process or similate feature selection accuracy from a model with known coefficients.  You'll be shocked at the  unreliability of lasso in the **ideal** case with zero collinearity: https://www.fharrell.com/talk/stratos19/

Comment: 1. Take each feature separately and calculate the root mean square error (RMSE; see Eq. (3)) for the estimated variable by using k-nn and cross-validation. 2. Select the feature that yields the lowest RMSE for the variable estimated. 3. Go through all features and calculate the RMSE in terms of the feature(s) already selected and the current candidate feature. 4. Select the candidate feature that yields the lowest RMSE with the feature(s) already selected. 5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 until addition of new features no longer lowers the RMSE of the estimated variable.  (Whitney 1971)

Comment: This is an other method i came accross.